# TeX and ASCII table code

Tags: characters

Is it possible a command like

```
\char{n}
```

where `n` is a number between 0 and 255? For example

```
\char{241}
```

returns **ñ** as output. I searched the web for something similar, even within this site, but I did not find anything

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. For sure, there is an instruction called `\char`.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve: a command  to print characters by his ASCII code. e.g. \mycommand{142} prints Ž

Comment: I don't understand. ASCII stops at 128, iirc. And doesn't contain many accented letters.

Comment: The extended ASCII ends at 255, or not?

Comment: Assuming you've loaded the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`, typing either `\char0241` or `\char241` prints out, you guessed it, `ñ`. A full MWE: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \begin{document} \char0241 \end{document}`. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, exaclty. I did not know of the existence of this command

Answer (score 13):

There is not anything called "the extended ascii" there are hundreds of ascii extensions "code pages" where the values between 128 and 256 might be accented latin letters as you have, or cyrillic, or Greek, or different accented letters depending on the encoding. So in latex you can use `\symbol{241}` (the latex syntax for `\char241`) but it depends on the encoding of the font you are using so normally you would never do that in a document.

If you use `\symbol{241}` in the body of the document but then change your font setup in the preamble you may get a different character with no warning or no character at all. The whole point about latex's encoding dependent commands like `\~{n}` is that the markup produces the correct character whatever numbers are used to access that character in the font being used.

Comment: May I humbly ask why this doesn't work on Math.Stackexchange? Are they using a special flavor of Latex that is more light-weight?

Comment: @aderchox they do not use latex at all, the "latex" rendering on most websites is mathjax which is javascript not tex. It emulates a subset of user-level latex math syntax but does not implement non-math commands like `\char` at all and doesn't implement any of the lower level tex commands that you might find in definitions on this site.

Answer (score 7):

The `\char` macro is somewhat special in that it does *not* expect its argument to be enclosed in curly braces. If `\char` is followed by a number (say, `241`), this number is taken to denote a base-10 number. If you write `\char"F1`, i.e., if you insert `"` after `\char`, the number (F1) will be interpreted to denote a hexadecimal number.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document} 
\char0241 \char"F1 % both will print out "ñ"
\end{document}
```