# Convert integer to its ASCII character

Tags: ascii

In the ASCII table, …

- `!` (exclamation mark) is also a printable character and its decimal representation is `33`
- `a` (latin small letter a) is a printable character and its decimal representation is `97`
- `}` (right curly bracket) is also a printable cahracter and its decimal representation is `125`

I want to know if there's a macro in LaTeX that converts a decimal representation to its ASCII character.

`\symbol{...}` returns `a` for `97` and `!` for `33`. I thought that `\symbol{...}` accomplished what I am looking for, but it returns `˝` (double acute accent) for `125`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\symbol{33} % exclamation mark
\symbol{97} % latin small letter a
\symbol{125} % it should return "right curly bracket", but it returns ˝ (double acute accent)
\end{document}
```

[image]

My question is: In the context of LaTeX, is there a built-in macro to convert an integer (i.e. decimal representation) to its ASCII character? The macro should work for any printable character in ASCII (i.e. between the range 32 to 126.)

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422025/tex-and-ascii-table-code) which is similar to my question, but it was conflated with the definition of "extended ascii table".

Comment: It can't work if the symbol is not available in the current font encoding. That would be rare for these characters, but far from impossible.

Answer (score 10):

The TeXbook says

> To get access to any character whatsoever, you can type
>
> `\char`⟨number⟩
>
> where ⟨number⟩ is any number from 0 to 255 (optionally followed by a space); you will get the corresponding character from the *current font*.

The default font is `cmr10`, in which the font character in position 125 ('175 in octal notation) is  ̋ . That's why `\char125` and `\symbol{125}` return  ̋ instead of right curly brace.

However, the `cmtt10` font is consistent with ASCII table (To confirm this, have a look at page 429 of the TeXbook). So, in order to have `\char125` produce the right curly brace, you can choose to use cmtt10 font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\texttt{\char33\char37\char97\char125\symbol{125}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another method is using `T1` font encoding, i.e., adding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\char33\char37\char97\char125\symbol{125}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The TeX primitive `\char number` creates a character with given code number. The TeX primitive `\Uchar number` creates a token with given code number. The second one is implemented only in XeTeX and LuaTeX. The difference is: `\char number` works after tokenization (in XeTeX or LuaTeX, the Unicode is accepted) and it is not expandable, `\Uchar number` returns a Unicode character: token of category 12 and it is expandable.

Answer (score 2):

As [wipet says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714152/73), at the primitive level, classical engines do not offer a way to generate a character by expansion. However, this can be done using macros: in `expl3` there is `\char_generate:nn` for this purpose, or for more general codepoints (full Unicode coverage), `\codepoint_generate:nn`. We might therefore do

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \mysymbol #1 { \codepoint_generate:nn {#1} { 12 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

to create a command `\mysymbol` that makes 'other' characters across the Unicode range by expansion.

Note that as [Stephen says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714150/73), this doesn't mean that a symbol will be printable directly.